# How can I use .cls in a subfile consisting of multiple .tex files in my project?

Tags: overleaf

I am writing my thesis, and I would like to append my resume to it. However, my resume is based on a template that comes with its own .cls file. I tried using \input \include. Overleaf generates blank pages. When I use *subfile* package and use \import, it does not work either, since I don't have preamble for resume.tex. How can I embed the subfile with its own .cls in a project?

My folder structure

main.tex
resume.tex

Chapters/*.tex
Resume Sections/*.tex
Resume Sections/resume.cls

The main.tex looks like

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book} 
% The oneside option ensures that all pages are similar. the default option 'twosides' distinguishes between left and right pages.
\usepackage{KUstyle}

% Resume Folder has it's own class file
%\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{subfiles}
%% If you want to modify from the default margins
% \usepackage[left= 1.1in, right = 1.1in, top = 1.5in, bottom = 1.5in]{geometry} % Set the margins
% \usepackage{layouts} % Use in combination with the command %

%%%% Personal setup %%%%%

%% bibtex Important package to use full citations: bibentry
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}


%% You can put all packages and personalized commands in the following document.
\input{setup.tex}

%%%% Template Related Setup %%%%%

%%% Front Page %%%
\ptype{Thesis}
\by{by}
\author{}
\title{}
\advisor{}

%%% Report parameters %%%

 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
 
%% Set Chapter title in header %% 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% plain style so that the header does not appear in the abstract
\fancypagestyle{plain}{         
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}}%

% margin
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

% required package for list of tables and figures
\usepackage{titletoc}

% double space 
\usepackage{setspace}


% new style for the mainmatter with the line under the title
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\newcommand\mymainpagestyle{%
\fancyhf{}      
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\footnotesize{\chaptername~ \thechapter~ |~ \leftmark}} \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} \headrule \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
\setlength{\headheight}{25pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

%%%%% Main %%%%%
\doublespacing

\begin{document}

% \pagevalues  % If you are using the package layouts and want to get the current layout margin values so you can tune them. They are displayed on the first page if you activate this option. Remember to uncomment the \usepackage{layouts} at the beginning of this document. 


%%%% Introduction %%%%
\begin{singlespace*} 

\maketitle

\end{singlespace*}

\frontmatter % to get a different numbering of the frontmatter and mainmatter.
\pagestyle{plain} % not to get a header in the introduction pages

\newpage \ \newpage % to skip a page 

\newpage
\section*{Resumé}
\label{sec:resume}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Resumé}
\input{resume}


%%%% Introduction %%%%
\mainmatter 
\mymainpagestyle{} % to get a header in the rest of the chapters (except the first page of the chapter)

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{chap:intro}
\input{chapters/Introduction/introduction}

\singlespacing
\chapter{}
\label{chap:chap1}
\doublespacing
\input{chapters/Chapter1/chap1.tex}

\singlespacing
\chapter{}
\label{chap:chap2}
\doublespacing
\input{chapters/Chapter2/chap2.tex}


\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

My resume.tex looks like

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{Resume Sections/resume_cls} % See the resume.cls file to import packages and edit formatting/style
\begin{document}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADING INFORMATION
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------




%-----------WORK EXPERIENCE----------- 
\input{Resume Sections/Work Experience}

%-----------TEACHING EXPERIENCE------------
\input{Resume Sections/Teaching Experience}

%-----------EDUCATION----------- 
\input{Resume Sections/Education}

%-----------JOB RELATED TRAINING-----------
%\input{Resume Sections/Job Related Training}

%-----------AFFILIATIONS-----------
%\input{Resume Sections/Affiliations}

%-----------PROFESSIONAL PUBLICATIONS-----------
\input{Resume Sections/Professional Publications}

%-----------REFERENCES-----------
%\input{Resume Sections/References}

%-----------ADDITIONAL INFORMATION-----------
%\input{Resume Sections/Additional Information}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to have your resume in a separate project, build it, download the PDF file, upload the PDF file to the directory for your thesis, and then use `pdfpages` to include the resume directly into your thesis file.

Comment: alternatively, you can automate this somewhat with a [customized latexmk configuration](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_does_Overleaf_compile_my_project%3F#Customizing_latexmk).

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you!